# NIC pipelining in networks

Tags: nic, pipelining

Can anyone please explain what is **NIC pipelining** and how it works? I had been studying a tutorial regarding Netscaler where I came across this term of *pipelining*. So can anyone explain about it?

Comment: If you could give a quote of the context that you discovered it in, it would be helpful.

Comment: Also, welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Alternatively, if you can't remember anymore, maybe just delete this question?